# Blend templates for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, expression-blend

I had thought that Blend 4 was supposed to have included  VS 2010 templates (for custom behaviors, etc).  I have both tools installed, but I do not see the templates in Visual Studio.  Is there something I need to do to install them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates for that are included as part of the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d197f51a-de07-4edf-9cba-1f1b4a22110d&displaylang=en).  The code for [Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.behavior%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx), [Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.triggeraction%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx), [etc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.triggeraction%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx). is also part of the SDK so you'll definitely need to install it if you want to use those classes.  I did some poking around and it looks like those Templates are only available from Blend, not Visual Studio (weird).

Comment: I have the blend SDK installed, but still no templates.  Is there some additional step I need to perform?

Comment: Nope, that should be sufficient.  Make sure you have the correct SDK version installed (either Blend SDK for SL4 or Blend SDK for .NET 4.0).  I don't know if mixing the earlier Blend 3 SDK with Blend 4 will work.

Comment: Weird -- I reinstalled Blend this morning (the blend install included the SDK's), I still don't see the templates in VS

Comment: I think the Blend 4 SDK installs are broken in this respect (and good luck getting support: all the Microsoft Connect tickets I open seem to get closed as "not our problem").  You could manually install them by copying the files from \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v4.0\Templates to your VS2010 install and registering them manually.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx for instructions.  Blend 3 SDK templates are the only ones that seem to register in Visual Studio (and then only VS2008).

Comment: Looks like that was the ticket (or as close as it's gonna get -- that caused a bunch of templates to show, but not the behavior one I was looking for)

Answer (score 0):

Blend is a Silverlight / WPF designer. The aim is to separate the design concerns from the development concerns. If you type File->New Project you should see projecct templates for Silverlight and WPF data bound and non-data bound projects.

Comment: Thanks -- I know what blend is.  I want to code some custom behaviors that I can plug in to blend's behaviors palette.  this post: http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=391 makes it look as though there are supposed to already be some VS templates for coding new behaviors, but I don't see them in my VS installation.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean to sound patronising. That blog post picture looks like a project item as opposed to a project template. You shoudl try installing the silverlight tools to see whether that item comes up. Just in the process of upgrading my VS2010 to SP1 now. I'll report back if I find anything

Comment: My appologies -- I probably came off a little terse (rough day).  I'm about to try Mike's suggestion (below) and reinstall the blend sdk.  Maybe something just didn't go right the last time.

Comment: np :) I see that you got quite a bit further with the other response.